# How to correctly handle the '[dcc32 Warning] W1002 Symbol x is specific to a platform'?

Tags: macos, delphi, multiplatform

I am preparing my code for porting to Mac and now I have to handle the 'specific to platform' warnings (that until now I hid).

So, I have a few places (very few) where I see the warning. To make my code multiplatform I did something like this:

```
Procedure SomeName;
{$IFDEF msWindows}
begin
 SomeWinPlatformSpecificCode;       <---------- warning here
{$ELSE}
begin
 MacAlternativeCode;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

So, my procedure will work on Mac but I still see the warning. How do I correctly solve this (without suppressing them forcibly)?

Comment: You can wrap it into `{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}YourCode{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM ON}` if there's no way out.

Comment: I was thinking about this but seems a bit... I don't know how to call it... not an elegant solution. Probably because I manually hide warnings. I never ever did that (except for platform warnings). I know it is ok to do it in this context but still... I was thinking that the compiler will see that the code is in a {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} encasement and will automatically know to shut up.

Comment: The compiler is not that smart.  The `platform` directive only tells the compiler that a symbol is platform-specific, but not to WHICH platform(s). So you have to tell the compiler what you want.  In this case, if all of the platform-specific code is adequately IFDEF'ed, I would put a single `{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}` at the top of your unit, or at least at the top of your `implementation` section.  But certainly not inside each IFDEF.

Comment: I think shutting the compiler at the top of the unit is not a good idea because when you add new platform-bind code... well... the compiler will shut up. Why do you think is not a good idea to put the PLATFORM OFF directive in each IFDEF?

Comment: The warning is just a hint for you to not expect this code is working on all platforms. Wrapping that code with the `SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF` is just the way to tell the compiler: "I saw and understood the warning and I did all to handle this". If you wrap and do not handle this you lie to the compiler and in the end you lie to yourself. Thats the whole story